# Angular Service for Kendo Dialog throws an error

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, dialog, angular-route-guards

I need to trigger a dialog through the CanDeactivate routeguard, if the user tries to navigate out of a page without saving the form. I'm following the solution suggested [here](https://dzone.com/articles/prevent-user-from-losing-unsaved-data-1).

I want to customize the confirm dialog used in the example, using the custom modal dialog we are using across the application. I'm planning to do it using the [Kendo Dialog Service](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/dialog/service/). I'm using the exact same example given in the link on one of the existing components in my app, but it's throwing the following console error:

```
Cannot attach dialog to the page.
Add an element that uses the kendoDialogContainer directive, or set the 'appendTo' property.
See https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/dialog/service/.          
at DialogService.push../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dialog/dist/fesm5/index.js.DialogService.open (index.js:770)
at DashboardLandingComponent.push../src/app/dashboard/dashboard-landing/dashboard-landing.component.ts.DashboardLandingComponent.open (dashboard-landing.component.ts:27)
at Object.handleEvent (dashboard-landing.component.html:52)
at handleEvent (core.js:30650)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:31720)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:31447)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:21246)
at core.js:29859
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:554)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
```

The strange thing is that I do have the `kendoDialogContainer` directive added on the page.

Dashboard.html:

```
 <button kendoButton (click)="open()">Harmless button</button>
  <div kendoDialogContainer></div>
```

Dashboard.component.ts:

```
import { DialogCloseResult, DialogService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';

public open() {
var dialog = this.dialogService.open({
  title: "Please confirm",
  content: "Are you sure?",
  actions: [
    { text: "No" },
    { text: "Yes", primary: true }
  ]
});

dialog.result.subscribe((result) => {
  if (result instanceof DialogCloseResult) {
    console.log("close");
  } else {
    console.log("action", result);
  }
});
```

}

Any idea where it is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kendoDialogContainer div needs to be in the app/app.component.html. Had this same problem and this solved it.